# Subtracting cells only when there is a value on another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

My spreadsheet looks something like this:

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1
10 7  2  5  11 =SUM(A1:E1)

A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2
X     X  X     =18

A3 B3 C3 D3 E3 F3
   X        X  =17
```

On the **F** column starting from **F2** I want excel to sum the value from **F1** and subtract values where the letter X is present. In my example the sum on cell **F1** is 35.
The value on **F2** should therefore be:
35(retrieved from F1)
-10(letter X is present on **A2** and since **A1** has the value 10 we subtract that value)
-2(same thing here, letter X is present on **C2** and since **C1** has the value of 2 we subtract that value)
-5(and same here aswell, **D2** has letter X present and since **D1** has the value of 5 we subtract that value).

So **35-10-2-5=18**. The value of **F2** should be **18**.

And on **F3** in my example the value should be **35-7-11=17**.

This formula should work for every row starting from **F2**.

How can I achieve this?

I'm thinking maybe using the IF ISBLANK function but I'm a noob.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a simple `SUMIFS` formula

```
=SUMIFS($A$1:$E$1,$A2:$E2,"")
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

put this in F1 and copy down. You must enter the formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter, as it's an array formula:

`=SUM(IF(A1:E1="x", 0, $A$1:$E$1))`